# Node js how to use "node_modules" library instead of "src =<cdn>"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I know that this is a recurrent question but I failed to see an answer that I completly understood.

I am using at my node js app, in my index.html some cdn adresses.

i.e.    :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

but I also have this folder in my `node_modules` directory.. so I don't really need to use the cdn. I can just use the file from my node_modules directory.

problem is how?
right now I have this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
```

in my server.js file.

but that is *not*  the path to my node mudles folder (which is under the same root path as my index.html).

I tried to write something like:

```
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/'));
```

and in my index.html to write something like:

```
<script src="scripts/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

but the application didn't even started when I got to localhost:3000
beacuse I got this error:

```
Error: ENOENT, stat  ......   at Error (native)
```

my questions are:
1. what do I need to write in my server.js instead of `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));`

2.what do I need to write in my index.html file instead of:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

---

this is the message I am getting when simply adding:

```
 app.use('/scripts', express.static(path.join(__dirname,
'node_modules')));
```

error:

```
Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\<path_to_my_project>\server_modules\index.html'
   at Error (native)
```

I don't know why it looks for the file there... I do have a folder named "server_modules" but this is not where my index.html is located...
this is my files structure

```
- my_project
- - server.js
- - index.html
- - node_modules
- - server_modules
```

this is my server.js

```
// ---------------- define third Party dependencies)
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var path = require('path');
var assert = require('assert');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');




// ---------------- config the app
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

 app.use('/scripts', express.static(path.join(__dirname,
'node_modules')));


// ---------------- define the server handlers (internal dependencies)
var dbHandler = require('./server_modules/dbHandler.js');
var httpRequesetHandler = require('./server_modules/httpRequesetHandler.js').getHttpRequestHandler(dbHandler, app,jwt,expressJwt);
var io = require('./server_modules/socketHandler.js').listen(http, dbHandler);

// ---------------- start the server
http.listen((process.env.PORT || 3000), function () {
    dbHandler.get_random_room();
    console.log('listening on *:3000 ' + __dirname);
});
```

also: I am using angular for routing on my single page app

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you're getting the error you're getting.  I was able to do what you asked successfully.  My steps:

1. `npm install --save angular-ui-router`
2. In my index.hml I
   wrote: `<script
   src='/scripts/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js'
   type='text/javascript'></script>`
3. In server.js I added:
   `app.use('/scripts', express.static(path.join(__dirname,
   'node_modules')));`

Ran it, no problems.

Looking at your code, it looks like you're pointing to a file path that shouldn't exist based on the angular-ui module structure.  You also should watch your path syntax in the html file, 'scripts/whatever' is not the same as '/scripts/whatever'.

** EDIT **

If you want to serve static files out of more than one location, you simply declare the middleware multiple times, for example:

```
// serve files in /public directory from the root of the site, e.g. http://example.com/index.html would serve the file /public/index.html
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// also serve files in /node_modules from /scripts.  So /node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js would be found at /scripts/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js
app.use('/scripts', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'node_modules')));
```

Comment: thanks for answer. added update to my original msg... tl;dr: the index.html is being searched under the wrong path now...

Comment: You need to have handlers for both sets of files.   Retain the middleware that points at __dirname/public to get the HTML (or wherever it's located) and a second as I configured to look in the node_modules as I demonstrated

Comment: thank you, just one small question - can you explain to me how do I retain the middleware that points at __dirname/public to get the HTML ?